# Python -Pandas _ Datetime conversion to a specific format such as DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, strftime

I have  column emp_date which consists of different date formats such as mm/dd/yyy, mm-dd-yyyy and also dd-mm-yyyy ,along with blank spaces, and some with timestamps.And the data type is Object for this column.

I want to convert these dates into the specific format such as DD-MM-YYYY .
Since it has multiple formats and blank spaces along with my specific format i am getting different errors.

Input file: CSV file

emp_date Column

10-07-2013

1/15/2012

Blank space or Null value

1/15/2023

12/13/2021

1-15-2021

Blank space or Null value

5/31/2013

Blank space or Null value

209-06-13 00:00:00

```
Code: 

col='Previous Employment Start Date'
CorePreviousWorkexp_bkp['col'] = pd.to_datetime(CorePreviousWorkexp_bkp[col], format='%d-%m-%Y')

or 

import datetime
def format(val):
    a = pd.to_datetime(val, errors='coerce', cache=False).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    try:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y')
    except:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y')
    return date_time_obj.date()
```

Output : But multiple errors  due to different formats and blank spaces.

Expected Format: DD-MM-YYYY

How to achieve this format ?

Comment: Drop the empty columns first?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. an example everyone can run, including some hard coded values that reproduce all errors.

Comment: In general, if you have mixed mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy, how would you differentiate between e.g. 9/5/2022 being the 9th of May 2022 or 5th of September 2022 ? Besides, you can set keyword `errors="coerce"` for pd.to_datetime, giving you `NaT` for strings that cannot be converted to datetime.

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. Formats *only* apply when parsing strings into dates or formatting dates as strings for display. Don't store dates as strings if possible. If you absolutely must, use the unambiguous ISO8601 format, ie YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Usually `pd.to_datetime` does a pretty good job with differently formatted dates.

I would try a `pd.to_datetime(df[col])`, and DO NOT specify the format you are looking for. This will allow the function to consider multiple date formats.

After this you can `df[col].fillna(somedate)`

and then reformat your `df[col]` as you please.

EDIT: to include @FObersteiner comment below, for dates which the `mm` and `dd` could be confused, you would likely need to parse these out yourself. For example `1/5/2020` vs `5/1/2020`. Only you would know which is correct.

Comment: pd.to_datetime assumes month first by default; if you do not specify a format, this will lead to incorrect conversions if the day comes first in the input.

Comment: `Only you would know which is correct.` not really. Only the person that initially created that date does. Maybe. It's simply not possible to safely parse date literals with mixed formats, unless the strings are valid in only a specific format, eg `01/31/2020`. Something like `1/5/2020` can't be safely parsed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's absolutely true, it would have to come from source. But for the sake of the question I didn't want to focus on poor data quality.